# Setting a Default Page in IIS

Tags: asp.net

I have published my web site on IIS in LAN . I want to display my login page as default. 
 how to set this page as default.

Answer (score 1):

You could set default document on IIS to your login page, but the best way would to do so would be to use your authentication provider mechanisms for authentication checking.

To give you a more specific answer you need to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

You mention the use of IIS and the LAN, but not much else:

- What version of IIS are you running?
- Is this site only available on the LAN?
- Are you using Windows Authentication or Forms Authentication?
- How have you configured the site in IIS - Anonymous users, Basic Auth or Integrated Auth?

Setting the login page as the default page in IIS as many others have suggested assumes that the login page is in the root of the site, that there are no subfolders, and that users will always request the site with no page names in the request.

Assuming you've set up an authentication provider, you can easily do something like this in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30000" path="/">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
<system.web>
```

This will ensure that any anonymous user is sent to the login page, regardless of the originally requested page or folder.

Answer (score 0):

In your IIS admin tool, open the properties diaolg for your virtual directory, navigate to the Documents tab, and add your pagename to the "default content page" list. Then move it up to the top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

In ISS7, when managing your site, there's an item called "Default Document", where you can arrange the order of default documents and add new documents.

Comment: Doesn't work if the the login page is in a different folder to the one the user requested though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS 7, you can just go to your IIS and select your website and click Default Document and add the login page that you want to set as Default.

Comment: And what if the user's request is to a folder that doesn't have a login page in it? Or if the login page isn't in the root of the site?